# Page load before jQuery loader 0-100%, it should be 0-100% then page load

Tags: jquery

My site loads page about 3 seconds then loading jQuery loader 0-100% to show page, it should  start by loading 0-100% then show whole page.

Here is my site :  http://html.multipixels.net/moodie/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
http://html.multipixels.net/moodie/js/custom.js
```

You are running the function

```
jQuery("body").queryLoader2({
```

on

```
jQuery(document).ready
```

Which means that the above function shall run only when the whole page and its elements have been loaded, if you wish to run it asap without waiting for the whole page to load then run it unconditionally as shown below..

```
jQuery("body").queryLoader2({
    barColor: "#3899b5",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    percentage: true,
    barHeight: 4,
    completeAnimation: "grow",
    minimumTime: 500,
    onComplete : function () { 
    self.loader.fadeOut(200);
                }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your replied, after I did like you advised the result is : it made jQuery conflict and it's not work.

Comment: ok, I just updated the code could you plz try again... and my apologies for the delayed response I was afk..

Comment: Thank you very much Wardha-Web , it works nice now :) also no need to apologies it should be me apologize you, I appreciated your help, thanks agian.